# Get type information for type declared in another assembly/project

Tags: c#, roslyn

So as the title says I'm trying to get type information from types declared in another assembly using Roslyn. Initially I tried to do this by manually looking through referenced assemblies but realised I didn't have namespace information.

I was expecting the below to work:

```
  var workSpace = Roslyn.Services.Workspace.LoadSolution(solFilePath);

  IDocument file = null;
  IProject proje = null;

  Compilation compilation = Compilation.Create("Test");
  List<CommonSyntaxTree> trees = new List<CommonSyntaxTree>();

  foreach (var proj in workSpace.CurrentSolution.Projects)
  {
    foreach (var doc in proj.Documents)
    {
      if (doc.FilePath.ToLower() == filePath.ToLower())
      {
        file = doc;
        proje = proj;
      }
      else trees.Add(doc.GetSyntaxTree());
    }
  }

  var targetTree = file.GetSyntaxTree();

  trees.Add(targetTree);
  var compilation2 = (Compilation)compilation.AddSyntaxTrees(trees);

  var semanticModel = compilation2.GetSemanticModel(targetTree);

  var root = targetTree.GetRoot();

  var className = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().ToList().ElementAt(1);

  var properties = className.DescendantNodes().OfType<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>()
      .Where(p => p.Modifiers.Select(syn => syn.ToString().ToLower() == "public").Count() > 0).ToList();

  var typeInfo = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(properties.First());

  var property = properties.First();

  var symbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(property);

  var symbol2 = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(property);
```

Neither `typeInfo` nor `typeSyntax` have the information that I need in them, what am I doing wrong here?

This is the class I'm parsing:

```
   class Foo
  {
    public Bar bar { get; set; }

    public Foo() { }

    public int GetInt(Bar bar, int ret = 5 ){
      return ret;
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to get Type information on the `Bar` class which is defined in another assembly.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do I have to build the entire compilation model for the solution or something?

Comment: var symbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(property);

symbol.Type contained the information I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't call `GetTypeInfo`. Instead, once you have the `PropertyDeclarationSyntax`, call `GetDeclaredSymbol` with that declaration syntax, and you will get the `IPropertySymbol` for that property. From there, you can grab `IPropertySymbol.Type`, which is the type you're looking for.

Comment: That worked, thanks Jason. Could you confirm for me whether I have to manually add the syntax tree of the type in the external assembly to get this to work? Seemed to be what I was missing.

Comment: Also the Type property you pointed out is of Type "TypeSymbol". Have you got a method of extracting the Type without using say Type.GetType("xxx")?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "extracting the type"? You mean getting the Reflection type? There's no good helper, partly because (typically) you can never assume the type you're compiling against is creatable at runtime. There's a strong (and often overlooked) distinction between "compile time" and "run time", and it's rare to bridge them.

Comment: The reason you weren't getting the original type is because when you created your new compilation, you didn't add the references. Therefore, the compilation had no way to know where Bar was coming from. Do that and it'll work great. Why not just ask the Project for it's Compilation? It looks like you're taking all the data we've nicely produced, ignoring it, and recreating it yourself. If you need to view the project in a slightly different way, take the Compilation and change it. Don't go recreating it yourself.

Comment: Compilations have syntax trees, references, a whole set of options (think debug/release, what language, etc, etc.) Just call Project.GetCompilationAsync() to get the compilation that represents your project. If you then want to add or remove extra trees from there for analysis, you call Add/RemoveSyntaxTree to produce a new compilation that's just like the old one, except for your changes.

Comment: The problem is the compilation I need crosses multiple projects. What would be handy is if I could get an entire solution compilation somehow? Or I guess just combine the compilations. Do you have methods for this I haven't see yet? Thanks for the well thought out answers btw.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "compilation that crosses multiple projects". Compilations can point to other compilations for project-to-project references if you are modeling the traditional build process. Each compilation represents an invocation of the compiler. I'm not exactly sure why you'd ever want to combine syntax trees from different compilations into one directly, but maybe I'm not being creative enough.